# novacode docx find page number

Tags: c#, docx, page-numbering, novacode-docx

I'm using Novacode DocX to generate a Word (DocX) document in C#.
At some point in the code, I have a reference to a paragraph object, and I'd like to know what page that paragraph is on. Unfortunately, there is no Pargraph.PageNumber option, or anything of the sort.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: I don't think it would be possible, since the paging information is not included inside the docx document, it can only be computed if you render the docx, and I don't think Novacode knows how to render docx.

Comment: I see what you mean, thanks for your response. Now I came up with a way to simulate the same behaviour, using a Table of Contents (since that uses placeholders for page numbers). However, when I edit the document, the ToC isn't automatically updated. Do you know if it's possible to use Novacode DocX to force update the ToC, or generate a new one, with only a specific header level?

Answer (score 0):

To generate a table of content you can use this code :

```
DocX myDocument = DocX.Load(FilePath);

TableOfContents ToC = fullReportDocument.InsertTableOfContents(
        title : "Your Title",
        switches : TableOfContentsSwitches.O | TableOfContentsSwitches.H | TableOfContentsSwitches.Z | TableOfContentsSwitches.U,
        headerStyle : null,
        maxIncludeLevel : 2
);
```

maxIncludeLevel is probably the parameter you want